# Spring-batch how to read variable length file using Itemreader having multibytes characters

Tags: spring-batch

I want to read a file which has fixed byte length in each row. But the encoding is "Big5" and have Chinese characters with 2 bytes, which changes the string length for each row.

So I'm not able to  tokenize the row based on `Range[]`. Because now the position on each parameter is getting changed because of above issue.

Is there any way where I can override the `FlatFileItemReader` class to read and tokenize based on byte length instead of string?

Data sample:

```
F2379E415CB20140326D2P0838 D2P0838«n«D¹ô«O¦u«¬²Õ¦X¦¡°Ó«~¡ã¶Ò¶°«¬                                                               ZAR2578014.180         2017032600000034282631278.150            11433.890           2016072299.5000             14.6600             20160627          175044.08020160731
```

with 295 length.

I have this mapping for all the fields

```
customerId=1,11
startDate=12,19

productId=20,27
productName=28,127
currencyCode=128,130
fxCurrentBalance=131,150
dueDate=151,158
applicationNbr=159,171
lastFxInterestAmount=172,191
fxInterestAmount=192,211
mtmDate=212,219
marketValue=220,239
cumulateGainsRate=240,259
lastGainingDate=260,267
ntdCurrentBal=268,287
snapshotDate=288,295
```

But when I convert it into Big5 its string length changes and I am not able to tokenize correctly.

Comment: Do you have the file with you? Please post an example file. I do not have any problem with Big5 Encoding with Spring Batch.

Comment: here is some sample data -

Comment: here is the encoded data which has varying size

Comment: "M2984E88C6B20140416D2P1288 D2P1288美元積極型組合式商品∼募集型                                                                 USD2512000.000         2024041600000034305500.000               1344.420            2016072254.0500             11.2000             20160718          385680.00020160731

"

Comment: "G236AFED2D320150615D2Q1205 D2Q1205南非幣保守型組合式商品∼募集型                                                               ZAR25149184.780        202006150000003467597            尚未配息            尚未配息20160722104.4700            尚未配息            尚未配息          334732.90020160731"

Comment: Could you upload an original file?

Comment: @Nghia Iam on closed network and cannot upload files to any of the public domain systems like google docs. The actual problem is the length of each row is not fixed after encoding it to Big5. All the rows have 295 bytes, but as Chinese characters are of 2 bytes the string length is varying

Comment: At home, you can create a sample file and upload. I need to verify my program with the correct file which you are using.

Comment: What indicates the end of a record if it's not byte length?  Have you tried implementing your own RecordSeparatorPolicy (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/separator/RecordSeparatorPolicy.html)?